# Error while trying to run 2-node-network.groovy example

Tags: unetstack

I am trying to learn and get comfortable with Unetstack so i thought that it would be a good idea to run through the examples to get some understanding. The problem however is that i run into an error at the first command i try `bin/unet samples/2-node-network.groovy` , i get the error below.

```
WARNING: An illegal reflective access operation has occurred
WARNING: Illegal reflective access by org.codehaus.groovy.vmplugin.v7.Java7$1 (file:/home/peder/unet-3.4.0/lib/groovy-2.5.9.jar) to constructor java.lang.invoke.MethodHandles$Lookup(java.lang.Class,int)
WARNING: Please consider reporting this to the maintainers of org.codehaus.groovy.vmplugin.v7.Java7$1
WARNING: Use --illegal-access=warn to enable warnings of further illegal reflective access operations
WARNING: All illegal access operations will be denied in a future release
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: object is not an instance of declaring class
```

It should show

```
2-node network
--------------

Node A: tcp://localhost:1101, http://localhost:8081/
Node B: tcp://localhost:1102, http://localhost:8082/
```

I am quite new to linux and tried to manually install java and groovy and just running the file from the folder with `groovy 2-node-network.groovy` and then got the error:

```
2-node network
--------------

Node A: tcp://localhost:1101, http://localhost:8081/
Node B: tcp://localhost:1102, http://localhost:8082/

Caught: groovy.lang.MissingPropertyException: No such property: RealTimePlatform for class: 2-node-network
groovy.lang.MissingPropertyException: No such property: RealTimePlatform for class: 2-node-network
    at 2-node-network.run(2-node-network.groovy:17)
```

I also tried to run form the simulator IDE and this worked fine.

Am I missing something crucial here?

Comment: check your `java -version` and see if it has correct version, it should show you `openjdk version "1.8.0_362"`, normally this indicate that you may have newer version of `java`.